# Selenium-python/ trying to upload an image by selecting the upload button and sending the path of the image as text but I get nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried
`WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "upload-file dropzone"))).send_keys(r"C:\Users\Dln\Desktop\wide.jpg")`

but I got nothing uploaded, it is clickable and it opens a window to choose the image from my system, I tried to use `keyboard.type(path)` after clicking the upload image button but it is not that efficient, so I was wondering about other methods.

here's the code for the button

```html
<div class="fileinput-button">
<div class="file-input">
<div class="kv-upload-progress kv-hidden" style="display: none;"><div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%;">
        0%
     </div>
</div></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<button type="button" tabindex="500" title="Abort ongoing upload" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary kv-hidden fileinput-cancel fileinput-cancel-button legitRipple"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>  <span class="hidden-xs">Cancel</span></button>

<div tabindex="500" class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-default font-weight-semibold btn-file legitRipple"><i class="icon-upload4 mr-2"></i>  <span class="hidden-xs">Upload images</span><input type="file" name="file" id="upload-file-wysiwyg-btn" class="file-input file-input-custom form-control form-control-sm alpha-grey" multiple="multiple" data-browse-icon="<i class='icon-upload4 mr-2'></i>" data-browse-label="Upload images" data-show-caption="false" data-show-upload="false" data-browse-class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-default font-weight-semibold" data-remove-class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-show-remove="false" data-show-preview="false" data-fouc=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative and effective way to upload with file path

```
import os
driver.find_element_by_id("field_id").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"\wide.jpg")
```

Comment: I got that error `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found` even though I am sure of the path

Comment: I solved it, thanks a lot, I had to add `\imagename.png` not the whole path

Comment: @Amr Awesome ! Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the element can be visible, but not yet clickable. Try using

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable
```

as the wait condition.

Comment: I got that as an error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: I'm not sure you are using the right element. Try using `file-input` instead of `upload-file dropzone` as the class-name selector.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "fileinput-button"))).send_keys(r"C:\Users\Dln\Desktop\wide.jpg")`

I used this, I actually pretty much tried every possible class name in the HTML that belongs to that button

Comment: Are you able to share url to the page?

Comment: You gotta have an ID and PW for that as it is a back-end website, do you have any social media accounts or an email that I can pass you the ID and PW on ?

Comment: No, better not then.